# Can I remove one of my badges?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page

Suppose I don't like one of the badges that I've earned.  Is it possible for me to remove it from my profile, and if so how?  I can't find any related options on my profile page.

Comment: Rare unique request. _Remov mah badje_

Comment: I enjoy standing out from the crowd.

Comment: If I'm ever awarded a bronze php badge I'm pretty sure I'd like to have it removed ;-)

Comment: Do you not like the name of one of the badges or something?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski that thought did cross my mind recently when I did, in fact, accidentally earn a bronze php tag badge recently.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I'm sorry to hear that, you have my sympathy.

Comment: @Lucas, Michael: You think you have it bad? I have a *gold* [php] badge.

Comment: ["Badges? We don't need no stinkin' badges!"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinking_badges)

Comment: It's a sensible request actually. Over time, you tend to gather score in all kinds of tags, even those that you don't know all that much about.

Comment: Another possibility is to earn so many badges, that the one you don't want to see is a lot harder to find.

Comment: How about writing a greasemonkey script that simply removes the badge from your view?

Comment: @Lundin Oh, god... I hadn't even considered that. I've got partial progress for the php badge myself.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

No, there is no built-in feature to remove a badge or hide it from display. Probably because you are the first person to have ever asked for it.

Such a feature is unlikely to ever be implemented, for the same reason. If you feel strongly that such a feature should exist, you can propose a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and make your case for it there. Prepare for such a request to be rather poorly received.

If this is just a one-off thing, and you have a particularly compelling reason why you need to have a badge removed from your profile, you could try contacting the Stack Overflow team (see the "contact" link in the page footer) and asking for them to help you. They would be the only ones who could do so.

(Update: [they are extremely unlikely to do so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334052/can-i-remove-one-of-my-badges#comment392623_334056), and even if you did come up with a sufficiently compelling reason to persuade them to remove a badge, the system would just automatically re-award it, since you still meet the criteria. Looks like your only way out is to request an account deletion, and then make sure not to earn the badge the next time. Whether or not that's actually possible depends on which badge it is that you detest.)

Note that badges are awarded for what the system considers to be *positive* actions, so you should be proud of the badges that you've earned.

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question. And as I share opinion that such feature introduction is unlikely I'll follow your 2nd advice. I shall contact the SO team to see if they can help me. I hope it's possible for an admin to do it manually.

Comment: Well, Stack Overflow Team writes in response to my query:
"We do not remove badges from user profiles. Even if we did, it would just get re-awarded to you because you still meet the criteria for it to be awarded."
So this is not an option either.

Comment: "Looks like your only way out is to request an account deletion, and then make sure not to earn the badge the next time." Haha, well there's always the sledgehammer approach.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, thanks for your efforts. And I'm sorry you got so many downvotes because of your position. The huge flow of comments can be easily wrapped with your words: "born of mean-spirited dismissiveness, not logic". I liked how your question "What's the actual harm?" got "this can have more severe consequences" :-)

Comment: Say I'm the only person with a gold tag badge and I just don't want to dupe hammer, then I should delete my account? Well, if that's the solution...

Comment: @ThomasWeller Then instead of closing as duplicate, leave a comment saying "possible duplicate of".  The difference is rounding error.

Comment: "Prepare for such a request to be rather poorly received" Like [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326492/shop-system-reputation-points-buyable-for-real-currency)?

Comment: Well, not quite like that. I don't think people would *hate* it, because removing a badge doesn't go against the fundamental premise of Stack Overflow like that proposal does, @doru. The opposition would be more of the "every feature starts at -100 points" variety. Very few people in the history of anything would be interested in giving up swag that they worked hard for.

Comment: But maybe they can **hide** the badge instead of actually **remove** it.

Comment: I completely agree with this answer, as I don't see a valid reason on removing a badge. However, you could agree on the fact that "Peer Pressure" is not a badge you could be proud of (OK, you've been disciplined enough to remove a bad post of yours, but it reports the fact that a bad post has been written!). Don't know if the OP intends that particular badge, though.

Comment: If it's a tag badge one is concerned about, re-awarding could be prevented by deleting answers/questions or editing tags.

Comment: That's still a good thing, though, @Andrea. I mean, everyone makes mistakes. You can't hide from that. The important thing is that you were willing to learn from your mistakes, and you cleaned up the mess afterwards!

Comment: I *do* have a VB badge now that I think about it...

Comment: Is the Peer Pressure badge considered a positive action? To many, that could be an embarrassment of how poorly-received one of your questions was, and you have no way to get rid of it.

Comment: @Davy Yes, I think it is, on balance, good thing. No one is perfect, and no one knows everything. So it's not really praiseworthy that you posted a bad answer, but it *is* praiseworthy that you learned from feedback and cleaned up after yourself.

Comment: `Note that badges are awarded for what the system considers to be positive actions` except for that retired `Tumbleweed` badge. I also don't view unsung hero badge as something positive personally because it's a sign that I've been answering ineffectively (answering questions that seems to only help the OP without benefitting anyone else).

Comment: Maybe that's why it was retired?

Answer (score 25):

IMHO nobody has suggested a working solution yet, perhaps because it was not known that your problem is related to the Necromancer badge. The procedure below may not work for all kinds of badges, but should for the Necromancer.

1.) Ask a moderator to disassociate your user from the answer.

2.) Wait until that is completed.

3.) Ask a moderator or Stack Overflow employee (not sure who can do it) to recalculate your profile because you want to get rid of the badge.

It will not automatically be re-awarded, because the answer is now given by an anonymous user and not you.

Next, just take care to not answer old questions again.

Comment: I like this solution because it does not involve harming other necromancers.

Comment: Maybe someone can comment on making old answers "Community wiki". While one would not earn reputation, would we still earn a badge?

Comment: @ThomasWeller _"The original author still gets badges based on community posts."_ From [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/266735) on MSE.

Comment: I have never _ever_ heard of badges being removed. There is no "Recalculation" of badges. Badges, once earned, are permanent.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I agree. I also never heard of that. There is certainly no automatic recalculation, but there could be a manual way.

Comment: This is what SO team told me: "_We do not remove badges from user profiles. Even if we did, it would just get re-awarded to you because you still meet the criteria for it to be awarded._"
Do you still think they would agree to recalc even if the answer will be effectively disassociated?

Comment: Badges *have* been removed in specific circumstances, like when they were obtained fradulently, @Cerbrus. It doesn't happen frequently, and it requires a community team member or a developer to do it manually (so no automatic recalc), but I have heard of it. Anyway, the only reason I suggested it is that's literally the only way to, in general, have a badge removed. I had very little confidence they would agree, but it's always worth a shot. Now that we know which specific badge he's interested in, Thomas's answer is really the best solution, and has my +1.

Comment: I forgot about fraudulent badges. This isn't a case of fraud, though. It's someone's feelings being hurt. I can pretty much guarantee that this request will be declined...

Comment: I followed advice from this answer and asked about these steps implementation. Result is not a big surprise either:
"_Number 3 is the problem - recalculation does not revoke badges. There is no existing process that ever revokes badges on our sites. It requires developers getting involved to manually alter things, and that's not something we bother them with just to revoke a badge off of someone's profile._"

Comment: And commenting about fraud precedents, the team representative told me: "_revoking badges requires developer intervention. A case of fraud where a user earned a large number of badges that are not deserved is potentially a situation where we would bug a developer to delete them all. One badge is not._"

Comment: @hypers: that's sad. I'd say, delete your account, create a new one, provide a nice answer somewhere, notify me here and I'll spend 100 rep as a bounty which should restore your current privileges

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Not sad. I'd say it's only logical. SE's dev team has enough to do without users coming in demanding badges to be revoked.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, thanks a lot for your compassion and a very generous offer. However, I don't think I was looking for this kind of solution. I was really after some kind of working way that anybody could use. But still I can delete my acc and I don't care much about priviliges etc. Once more - Danke schön!

Comment: Recalculate the profile?

Answer (score 14):

No, you can't remove it. Badges are awarded *automatically*, and they're cool [because](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges):

> you receive badges for being especially helpful

I can imagine you're not happy with your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438282/shape-with-macro-assigned-on-a-protected-chart-sheet-excel) earning a [Tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed?userid=4684507) badge, but trust me, it is pretty hard to do so intentionally. Actually, Tumbleweed is more of a 'consolation' badge. Just note that [by no means](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325653/4751173) it means that it is a bad question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Glorfindel . I understand and agree with your point. But my request is not related to the Tumbleweed badge. In fact I find it quite cool. If I'm able to remove badges from my profile I'll keep this one :-)

Comment: @hypers OK, I'm curious which one you want to have removed, then.

Comment: It's a silver badge (what a shame) for "Answer a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times."
The milestone is perfectly valid. But the name is terribly abortive. I totally don't accept it. But I don't want people to think otherwise.

Comment: @hypers So you're offended by the badge name being 'Necromancer'? Perhaps a better thing would be to suggest renaming the badge to something more neutral then, although I've no idea how the community would react to it.

Comment: @Stijn, yes, you are right. And your idea is probably much better. Though impact would be more global than removing from one profile. I can't foresee reaction either.

Comment: Yeah, actually, I can see how the "necromancer" name would be rather shocking to some people. It is an old BBS-ism, but for those unfamiliar with that particular idiomatic usage, it would carry an entirely different meaning. I would upvote a feature request proposing an alternative name, if you can come up with a good one, @hypers.

Comment: Anyone who cares can vote for a request here:
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334127/rename-the-badge

Comment: Oh dear, isn't this my favorite badge. Shakin' up old forgotten thingies.

Comment: @hypers - No way to vote - the post has been locked

Comment: @hypers I can't post on the locked thread but wanted to say this: A word is just a word. It has whatever meaning it is given by its context; no more. I occasionally find myself offended when people use a certain word with derogatory connotations. But I have to remind myself that usage of the word has changed over time; people using it now are not intending to be derogatory and may not even be aware of the connotations. I'd encourage anyone who is offended by any word to step back and consider the intention rather than the word itself. The world would be much happier place if everyone did this.

Answer (score 10):

Since it is the Necromancer badge that you don't want associated with your profile, then I suggest first requesting an account deletion. Then start over. In the future don't answer any questions more than 60 days after they are asked and you won't be in danger of getting the badge again. That way you can still be an active participator in Stack Overflow while not having to offend your conscience.

Comment: An account deletion would probably be overkill.  IIRC in the past Stackexchange has disassociated questions or answers from a user account on request.  While there's no guarantee that they'd do it in this case, it would be a much less disruptive option.