# Is it bad form to answer an old question with the answer you wish was there before?

Tags: discussion, answers, old-questions

At the end of a search through old Stack Overflow questions, after I finally figure out a problem, I sometimes find myself wanting to go back to a really old post to provide the answer that I wish I'd seen there hours before. Is that bad form?

Comment: [Relevant](https://xkcd.com/979/).

Comment: There are no threads on SO. Just questions,answers and comments. SO is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site. If your answer provides new insights, its welcome, no matter how old the question is.

Comment: Since the answer you plan to provide is noticeably different from those already present, it is fine.  Adding a new answer that is not imparting new information is not a good idea.

Comment: No. Truth is not a function of time.

Comment: @EJP It is exactly 10:02AM.

Comment: @EJP well, it never used to be.

Comment: @EJP Sometimes truth is indeed a function of time. The best way of solving a particular problem may change as technology advances. I'm never sure how SO aims to deal with that. For example, flagging a question as a duplicate is very unhelpful if the answers to the original question are out of date.

Comment: "Truth is not a function of time".  How odd!  SO is *the epitome* of the fact that information dates ridiculously quickly, in computing.  *Almost every* answer on here, more than 18 months old, is not only "utterly incorrect" but usually just incoherent, doesn't even apply - the whole API, operating system, or milieu has changed so much. Obviously.

Comment: Answering old questions with the answer I wish was there is one of the ways I give back to the community.  I'm always surprised at how many up-votes I get for doing this (my second highest up-voted answer comes from an answer I posted 2 years after the question was asked).

Comment: @MichaelKay The answer, *in theory* is to post the new answer and since it is more correct, it will rise to the top in votes over time.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

No, that's perfectly fine. In fact, we even offer [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) for answering old questions with good, new answers.

[image]

Comment: Some people aren't comfortable with the term "Necromancer". Perhaps that badge could be renamed to [Post-mortem communicator](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Department_of_Post-Mortem_Communications) :)

Comment: I never noticed that the bronze badge in that series is harder to get than the silver. Strange.

Comment: How about "Resuscitator"? Or "Revivifier"?

Comment: I'm sure there are many people who are not in the least concerned about the name of the Necromancer badge.  This comment is added in part to give such people a way to indicate that they agree — there isn't a way to down-vote the other comment.

Comment: @PM2Ring - [There was already a feature request for this.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334127/rename-the-necromancer-badge) It wasn't received well.

Comment: I for one appreciate fresh answers on old questions myself. As for necromancer, usually proud to wear the term, not a sensitive type.

Comment: @NathanTuggy because it has to be first answer, only [these questions could allow you to get one](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+score%3A0..+answers%3A0+closed%3A0)

Comment: Since the validity or context of an answer can change over time, I find it especially useful to find a recent answer filling in the gaps, as it were, as the the question will likely remain valid.

Comment: @BSMP Interesting! To be honest, I _was_ being frivolous with my previous comment, hence the smilie. I mostly wrote that comment to post the Discworld link. I'm quite proud of my recently-acquired Necromancer badge, and I personally don't mind the name at all... and I _definitely_ don't have a skull ring. ;)

Comment: I just have to add.  Ironically, that is how I started on Stack Overflow.  I kept arriving at an answer that only "half-answered" my question.  At the time it was 2+ years old (I think).  The third time, I put in my answer (which in retrospect isn't even the best), which was upvoted and accepted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In fact, some (including me) think that Necromancer seems cool, and do not think much about the possible negative connotations of `Necromancer`.

Comment: But no-one likes to be forced to wear a badge that they don't like, so either you should be able to decline a badge, or the names should be totally uncontroversial. I've complained in the past about "Strunk and White".

Comment: @MichaelKay Conversely, no one should have a badge they like stolen and replaced with one they don't like, so by that logic the name shouldn't be changed.  Perhaps it would be best if, for controversial badges, they had an alternate name available?  That way, if someone doesn't like the primary name, they can choose to use the alternate one instead.  ...The problem would be getting people to agree on good alternate names.

Comment: Are there really people complaining about badge names ? Man do people get offended easily nowadays... It's a badge. A virtual one. On a programming related page. Grow up...

Comment: @Tim I think a lot of people are uncomfortable with that term because of how necromancy is discussed in the major texts of various religions. For example, both the Bible and the Qur'an specifically condemn anything having to do with necromancy. So, that badge has a name that is problematic for many users in a way that most badge names are not.

Comment: Well they they can avoid it by being careful not to answer questions more than 60 days after they've been asked XD

Comment: @PM2Ring and everyone I'd be honest, since day one when I saw the `Necromancer` badge I wanted one. Blame it on too much AD&D but Necromancer badge is way coool. I respect your point of view to all of you though.

Comment: I for one think we should retire `Strunk and White`. Not because it offends me but because that book has ingrained a tremendous amount of ignorance about the English language among so many people, and stackoverflow shouldn't support that. (As pointed out by learned people like [Geoffrey K Pullum](http://www.chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497))

Comment: @oulenz But at least people are reading :/ The problem is more that people don't challenge information at all and just adopt it as truth in an instant. You can't blame that on the book or its authors. There is a world of obesity out there that is caused by the same problem; not books or false scientists spreading nonsense - people accepting what is said without any challenge at all. Its in a book or someone who looks smart says it, thus it is true. And so we have legions believing that eating less and avoiding fat is the key. Sigh.