# User's political display name triggering government action against users who view it - what should I do?

Tags: support, users, display-names

What real action can one take in regards to a user display *name* (to distinguish from a user profile) that potentially endangers (not just "offends" - can cause them harm or damage from a third party) another user or group of users.

Before asking I tried reading some other related or relevant questions like:

from meta.stackoverflow.com:

- [Are political avatars and profiles OK?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267368/are-political-avatars-and-profiles-ok)
- [Are political profiles that could possibly affect the participations of other users allowed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298950/are-political-profiles-that-could-possibly-affect-the-participations-of-other-us)
- [Should political (possibly offensive) content be allowed in user's profile?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270347/should-political-possibly-offensive-content-be-allowed-in-users-profile)

and on meta.stackexchange.com:

- [Non-neutral political phrases and terms in user profile and messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293481/non-neutral-political-phrases-and-terms-in-user-profile-and-messages)
- [Is it acceptable to insult god in a user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231334/is-it-acceptable-to-insult-god-in-a-user-profile/231362#231362)

But in those I mainly found opinions - and I did not find any answer as to what real action I can take. Plus I am also not sure as to where to ask this question (MetaSE, MetaSO?)

The issue I am referring to is related to at least one specific user display name and profile that has political messages and keywords embedded in its username or user display name (not only profile) which relates to a specific regime in a specific territory.

Now, the reason why I contemplated a lot before asking this question is because:

- Although frequently visiting and working at that specific territory which it effects I am not a citizen there, not a part of that ethnicity, so that political issue is as far away from me as can possibly be
- I am liberal enough to know and understand that I personally should not care (and on a personal level - I really don't) about other people's opinions.

On the other hand:

- this case is about a user**name** and not the profile. Profile page is easy to avoid - but a username appears everywhere (comments, answers, and even own profile
- in that specific territory, the embedded words are not considered offensive (which I don't care) but potentially *illegal* , *Harmful* or even *DANGEROUS*
- although I am not an integrated part of that territory on a personal level, I do have peers, colleagues and employees that I care about
- that specific territory is known for having very efficient and rigorous internet censorship and firewall technologies
- the situation HAS already actively effected me personally, my work, and my employees.

Unfortunately, I am not talking only about imaginary, would-be fantasy possibilities.

- I was working with a client that is related to the government and, while browsing my **own profile**, that username appeared. The official that was staring with me at the screen was shocked - because of me being a "foreigner", we moved on, but with palpable tension in the air. A day later I got a notice that the contract was cancelled.
- One of our employees has opened a question that this user(name) was involved in without taking the required precautions (Proxy-VPN-IpSpoofing), and our office immediately suffered a retaliatory 10 hour internet outage!
- I had to purchase, install and maintain a special infrastructure only in order to be able to *safely* work with SE (which we use a lot naturally) - all that because of that specific username.
- In the last few weeks, each time the specific username appears in a question or comment that is accessed from our offices, our office is promptly disconnected from the ISP for 30 minutes (and an overwhelming increase in attempt to sniff and penetrate network and devices).

I do understand (and am also happy about) the fact that SE is an apolitical website/community, and does not want to be involved in any of this, or to take any action in regards, but I feel that it is a bit unfair that one (or more) users are taking actions that can affect others that are totally innocent, passive bystanders (and I do not mean "offend" - I mean real palpable effect). I also understand that for people who are not involved in the territory, who do not work with its people, or do not know its political panorama, would not understand or care about this issue.

But, on the other hand, this issue can also potentially have a great effect on the community/website, because eventually the whole site could be banned from the territory, which would effect many other innocent users and would also be a big lost in traffic from that vast territory.

In that regard, IMHO the community must know the difference between **offensive** and potentially **dangerous** to other users.

What to do? Since one [can not flag a profile or username](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285204/flag-user-profile), and the option of directly addressing the user seems to have predictable results (reading also other previous comments and discussions) and might be labeled inappropriate, I am now not sure what I have to do in regards to a real action, and how to handle this situation. Who to contact and how?

For obvious reason I do not want to specify the exact username or a link to the profile - I do not want to cause any backlash to that user, or myself. Although I am quite sure that everything is transparent enough even if not specified, if any of the SO/SE staff would want more details, I will provide them in am more direct way (not in the question/comments).

**Edit after comments:**

I feel I need to add some point here, after seeing the comments.

- First of all, my plead to not post the specifics in in comments in order to avoid the exact context was edited out (not sure why).
- I feel some members miss the difference between "insulting" or "offensive" and "harmful" or dangerous".
- By using words like "totalitarian" and "oppressive regimes" (however might be true)- one DOES make a political statement, so it is hard understand how one, at the same time, is being apolitical.
- I feel I must again sharpen the point of this not having to do with political "offensive" or "insulting". This has to do with the fact that one user, is deliberately, and with clear and stated intent, is trying to harm another group of users for own gain. Unfortunately, me and my employees are in the second group (of being harmed).
- I do not think I need to get into the discussion of what is to be considered "dangerous" or "harmful" like some members suggested - and also I did not want to dramatize the original question -  But me being deported , or being put on some black-list that would delay border crossings , or even being visited by some 1984-like thought police thugs , or one of my employees being held for questioning - is "dangerous" or "harmful" enough. and yes -  Even an internet outage is harmful - especially when it is being done deliberately by one member of the community towards the others.
- I do not have nothing against the specific user, their political views or stands. As I recall, the user was even helpful to me numerous times (hence their appearance on my profile page).
- PLEASE do not turn this into a one-specific-regime-political-discussion. it is not about the right of a specific user to express his feelings or thoughts or his actions, it is about the **CONSEQUENCES** of these actions on other , third party , by-standers users and members of the community - who happens to live in a certain territory under certain rules ( well known to the user who exploit that ) . Maybe I used the wrong words for the title as " political" might be interchangeable with " harmful " for the intended meaning . it might take off the edge or vector of political discussion.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect case for the [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) link.

Comment: "For obvious reason I do not want to specify the exact username or a link to the profile" That's OK, it's pretty damn obvious (even before getting to your links) who exactly the user you're referring to is anyway. You didn't really have to sugarcoat the fact that the name was set up that way on purpose - that's exactly what the user wants everybody here to know.

Comment: *"while browsing my own profile , that username appeared"* - I don't see where on a profile the name of another user should appear. I'm curious what name you might refer to, but respect that you don't want it to be mentioned. I'd have a closer look at your profile, to figure out the name, but am afraid to do so: The word "Obmerk" is a strong, obscene insult in my language, and I don't want to get into trouble with my employer. (Note: This comment may contain traces of irony, possibly mixed with hints about my subjective view on this topic)

Comment: @Marco13 I think the issue here is more along the lines of a user in Thailand browsing a profile [named "Death to the king".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lèse_majesté_in_Thailand). Or browsing a profile with [Charlie Hebdo cartoons](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/01/07/charlie-hebdo-cartoons-paris-french-newspaper-shooting_n_6429552.html) in [Pakistan](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/apr/26/lynching-of-a-student-sparks-uproar-in-pakistan-against-blasphemy-laws). Although I don't know how big of an issue this is, and how practical/necessary it is for us to do anything about it

Comment: @Pekka웃 My (ironic) remark referred to the difficulties that arise from ... the attempt to avoid difficulties.More serious: I'm from Germany, and the Unicode character 5350 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika#Written_characters) is 卐, which is [illegal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strafgesetzbuch_section_86a) here (!) - should it be banned from usernames? Also for countries where this is a symbol of luck? Of course, one has to consider that the username referred to was *intended* to be insulting, but it's a thin line. There are some ridiculous rules out there. Hard to obey them all...

Comment: So, we have Donald Trump, Hillary, Swasitkas, or Che avatars? I'd recommend we ignore such things.

Comment: If an oppressive regime cuts off the internet of anyone who sees certain words, I don't think the words are the problem here.

Comment: How is your ISP even able to read SO's traffic when SO uses https? It should be end-to-end encrypted

Comment: @Ferrybig Because HTTPS isn't site-wide yet? It's still perfectly possible to use the HTTP version of SO (they don't seem to have the headers in place to automatically redirect/upgrade insecure requests).

Comment: @Marco13 yes, I'm generally in the "we shouldn't cater to every oppressive regime's whim" camp too, but I suppose in very special situations (as this one might have been) there's nothing wrong with moderator intervention.

Comment: @4386427 - As BoltClock indicates, it's not too hidden in here. See [the second post linked above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298950/are-political-profiles-that-could-possibly-affect-the-participations-of-other-us).

Comment: @4386427 You don't need to point out a specific user or post to talk about the actions (if any) that need to be taken in the general case.

Comment: @4386427 Absolutely not, this discussion needs to be generic so we can apply it to all situations.

Comment: The user in question is http://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/ciro-santilli-709%e5%a4%a7%e6%8a%93%e6%8d%95-%e5%85%ad%e5%9b%9b%e4%ba%8b%e4%bb%b6-%e6%b3%95%e8%bd%ae%e5%8a%9f

Comment: @Marco13 - As for usernames in own profile, you can try to browse other sections ( tabs ) of a profile . as for my own username - I can usually  appreciate irony or sarcasm , but not when people lives are at stake - and by reading the vocabulary in your comments ( "Insult" ) I think you are missing the point regarding the difference of being " offensive " ( which I stated I do not care ) and being " harmful " or "dangerous" towards a group with a stated intent to be so .

Comment: @jwg are you sure? The asker claims that she would be *endangered* by viewing this name. China's censorship regime is undeniably totalitarian, but I'd never heard of them imprisoning people for accidental viewing of banned material. Are things there even worse than I realised?

Comment: @jwg - I think this was uneccessary to post the exact name as it was pretty clear to everyone who bothered to read the whole question and links attached . ( and was specifically asked not to - see original before edit -  in order not to turn this into a political discussion )

Comment: As per @MarkAmery's comment, perhaps it was worth posting the username so we can judge the extent to which the consequences are dangerous as opposed to inconvenient or embarassing. The question does not state that someone could be imprisoned for viewing this username, just that to do so could be dangerous, and the only example of danger given is the temporary loss of one's internet connection.

Comment: @jwg indeed - while I might be ignorant about the extent of China's regime of political suppression, as far as I can tell the issue here is not "I might be lynched or imprisoned for visiting a page with this username", as I originally imagined, but rather just "government contacts might disapprove of me visiting a page with this username, and I might lose business as a result". Those are *extremely* different risks, and to frame the latter as being "endangered" - if that is indeed what Obmerk is doing -
 seems to me to be a gross exaggeration.

Comment: @MarkAmery I agree.

Comment: @jwg  - the unnecessary  specific ( for those who did not read all )  was already answered more subtly before in a comment by Brad Larson.

Comment: I get your wanting this discussion to be generalized, but you mention several actions this regime takes which makes the particular situation only really relevant to that one particular regime, because they're the only ones in the world that do this on such a large scale. It's pretty hard to generalize a conversation about all the black sheep in the room when there's only one black sheep in the room. It's causing two different conversations here - one that's generalized to political messages which don't matter because other countries don't block you for viewing it, and one that's more specific.

Comment: @animuson . you are totally right . It is causing two conversations. and that is the exact reason why I did not want to get specific - as to not alienate the discussion from the core .

Comment: I really wonder what the odds of somebody writing you who shares your habit of placing spaces before every comma, full stop and brackets are...

Comment: Hi, how did someone else's username appear in your profile? Forcing HTTPS should solve ISP issues.

Comment: @CiroSantilli709 - The user name appears on the [questions tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7586/kobi?tab=questions).

Comment: @Marco13, In those countries where the swastika is a symbol of luck you'll see that the hooks (for want of a better word) turn the other way round from the nazi symbol.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was tagged [support] but acknowledges the existing [support] position is unambiguous and intentionally has no such feature to provide help on.

Comment: @idmean: Most likely it was translated by Obmerk Kronen, hence the similar typographical idiosyncrasies.

Comment: You now published someone's opinion piece which promotes a concerted effort to get SO banned in China with the stated goal to pressure Stack Exchange Inc. into applying CCP censorship rules here - or face economic losses. You should definitely roll back this edit.

Comment: So the person in question commented a few comments above this, now looking at this question will also create problems. i agree with a comment in a related post about his user id - thinking it will force chinese programmers to revolt is naive. China can and probably will simply provide its own Q&A site. It's not that hard and they've done it before.

Comment: Trying to make a site suffer just so they care or whatever, dragging them into something they have nothing to do with, just because one belongs to it, is opportunistic as well. If they really care, let them write about it on a personal site. Getting victimised for their views will probably have much more effect, as is evident elsewhere in Asia. Causes way more outrage. And if they're not willing to risk it all, why would any other programmer? Plus, since this is an apolitical site, I don't see why ppl should be allowed to use it for political purposes.

Comment: This user has changed their name multiple times. The most recent ones are variations on "July 4 incident" and "Falun Gong". Are we going to ban these particular phrases from user names? Or is the rule just going to be against anything that seems likely to annoy the Chinese authorities? Could I have the name "Falun Gong" in Roman letters as my username or is it only Chinese characters that are a problem? It's rather extreme for SO to ban all mention of a meditation and exercise program. That's what makes it different from banning racism and hate speech - the bizarreness and arbitrariness of it

Comment: So are we here to take a Stand?

Comment: Reopening because: Seriously? How is this _not_ about SE/SO?

Comment: FYI, I've moved the email you received from another user and edited into the question to its own (community wiki) answer, as I feel the email itself seems to be an attempt at an answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349206/1157054

Comment: To be honest, I feel the PO does not agree with the username, and is turning it into a legal argument to exert censorship pressure on SO. If we allow this, it opens the way for others to follow suit.

Comment: By doing this, said user is causing a large negative impact on innocent users, and likely zero impact on said user's target. This is absurd. I applaud you for taking a stand, but you're using the wrong platform. You're not causing the changes you want to happen, you're just inconveniencing innocent people. (@ the user with the troublesome username)

Comment: It's still unclear how user A's name could be a "danger" to user B or user C, especially if it's an incidental sighting. Even the scenario which you describe, where someone would end a contract with you because you were on a page where some offensive word appeared seems like a fundamental lack of understanding about the internet and about mature adulthood that the username in question is not really the issue here, but the people you are doing business with.

Comment: As a related question, should usernames perhaps be limited to the ascii range of 34 to 91? Namely, A-Z,a-z, and 6 common symbols?

Comment: @TravisJ sounds like a different question to me. Personally I'd be against it - this sort of thing could be done even within that range, and denying people the ability to have their actual (non-ascii) name seems harsh...

Comment: @TravisJ: That's very hard to do retroactively, as you'd by mutilating the attribution which is required by the CC BY-SA license.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen Methinks you should be taking this complaint to your authoritarian government that is blocking websites based on keywords. SE imo has no obligation to bow down to authoritarian governments, regardless of what stupid laws they enact.

Comment: @Magisch - Here's a template: "Hello powerful and unreasonable government *X*. I accidentally and repeatedly broken your unjust and undemocratic laws by inadvertently keeping online contact with an anti-*X* activist (you know how you discriminate against *Y*? My contact is related to *Y* too!). Can you please change the laws, along with your entire system of government? PS. I am a *foreign citizen* working here on a temporary visa you've granted me. If you could be so kind as to not arrest or deport me and everyone around me that would be really neat." (yes, I am being snarky)

Comment: @Kobi Great template,  to complete this [support] request, SE just needs to get its act together and make a button to force that template on all users. Then regimes can monitor its use (or results) and penalize "lazy" citizens who don't report on others. Finally, sensitive state organs wont fear accidentally hurting "apolitical" state associates who want to help bring about an Orwellian future but don't know which lever to press.

Comment: @BenVoigt - The attribution is to account, essentially the user id, and not the username itself. Otherwise if you changed your username, then you would be implying that no ones attribution would be valid any more, which isn't the case, as attribution is supposed to include a link to the post which has in turn a link to the author's primary identifying number. So no, there would be no "mutilation" as you put it.

Comment: @TravisJ: Are you willing to make that argument before a judge?  Willing to risk damages for willful infringement?  The license says what the license says.  StackOverflow's separate page suggesting a link to the user profile page is not part of the legally binding license.  And even if it were, changing the user name also removes it from the profile page, so you can't even click through to get the correct attribution as specified by the author.

Comment: @BenVoigt - "The license says what the license says"? That is a tautology which lacks relevance here. I honestly don't attribute anything of legal value to your comment, nor your original assertion of "mutilation". You are not a lawyer. Law requires a burden of proof that I just don't see you providing for such grand posturing here. Take your tin hat elsewhere.

Comment: @TravisJ: My proof is found in section 4(c) of the license, which is quite clear that attribution requires providing the name or pseudonym of the author.  The username is the pseudonym specified by the author.  I doubt you can provide equivalent support for your assertion that the author's "primary identifying number" satisfies the license.

Comment: "The credit required by this Section 4(c) may be implemented in any reasonable manner;", it specifically states. That aside, usernames are not required to be unique, thus, you cannot simply assume using a username is actually proper attribution. The URI to the source *must* be included, and this reference is where the author's primary identification of the work is located.

Comment: How can this happen with a  **HTTPS connection**? Someone behind you will see it. Anyone else? How???

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - not to open the discussion again - but yes, DNS leaks got nothing to do with `HTTPS`

Answer (score 87):

A political statement in a display name is effectively an advertisement. It's designed to be a catchy word or phrase that captures your attention and diverts you to their profile where you can read more. Whether they're advertising politics, a product, or an [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) proposal, there is nothing inherently wrong with using your display name as an advertisement for whatever you'd like to advertise, and an unsolicited political statement is not much different than an unsolicited product advertisement in that regard.

The tricky part here is that sometimes those advertisements aren't in the best of interests of *all* users. In this particular instance, it's inhibiting some users who fall behind a much more restrictive firewall that could effectively cut off their access to our site, even if only temporarily. So the question comes down to: do we act on advertisements which cause problems?

Well, that's not as simple as it may sound. Users are right that our network tends to be very apolitical, but that does *not* mean politics are not allowed. It simply means we're not interested in them, don't care, and don't take a stance on most issues. Censoring an advertisement that a user has integrated into their profile is effectively asking us to take a stance. And not just that, but also analyze the situation to come to a educated conclusion about the issue. For example, you refer to the situation as harmful and dangerous, but others might strongly disagree with that sentiment and only refer to the situation as inconvenient.

Analyzing in a fair way is not an easy task to take on, and we're certainly not interested in starting any sort of queue of things to analyze. All in all, it's unfortunate some of the things you mention in your question actually occur to some of our users, but we can't consider them in making a decision like this. Considering them gives an implicit weight to the country who enacts such a policy that their policy is acceptable and that others are willing to follow and enforce to prevent those actions from occurring.

To summarize: **Yes, political statements are allowed in display names.** Calling for them to not be allowed there is calling for any advertisement in a display name to not be allowed, which is simply not something we can enforce adequately, or really have any interested in enforcing. We're sorry if that policy causes issues with viewing our site due to particular phrases, but keep in mind that we and the users with these display names are not the ones actually causing problems for you.

Comment: I really respect you cautios answer and also, what it stands for . But I find hard to agree with the demagogic-in nature point ( that others have tried to express ) that _" keep in mind that we and the users with these display names are not the ones actually causing problems for you"_ . well, I will take it to the extreme and ask if one plants evidence to a crime in another person's property, can he really say _" it is not me that caused the harm, it is the police, or the court system... "_ ? .this is demagogic argument.that is especially true if that person has explicitly express that goal...

Comment: @ObmerkKronen Well a huge difference there is that normally if you just planted evidence somewhere, you'd still have to be investigated and proven guilty. Especially in this day and age, it's much easier to prove whether evidence was planted or not. A key difference here is that someone blocking you for simply seeing something on a screen is assuming you are guilty with no trial whatsoever. That *isn't* the person who planted the evidence causing the problem. A competent law enforcement agency would figure out who planted the evidence, not just immediately convict the person it was found on.

Comment: _" A competent law enforcement agency would figure out "_ so we are now putting this in the hands of the same government officials that , by your argument, is the root of the problem ?

Comment: *Calling for them to not be allowed there is calling for any advertisement in a display name to not be allowed,* This is a bizarre non-sequitur.

Comment: *an unsolicited political statement is not much different than an unsolicited product advertisement in that regard.* Well, it's completely different, especially if the "statement" is intended or designed to shock or offend certain constituencies, and/or is actively harming other users of the service, not to mention when it is illegal. For instance, a username glorifying Maoist rebels in eastern India would be illegal to use or even possibly view. Whether or not we agree with such laws, it's hardly SO's role to engage in civil disobedience out of some abstract (American) principle.

Comment: @torazaburo: "*it's hardly SO's role to engage in civil disobedience out of some abstract (American) principle.*" Is it SO's role to prevent acts of civil disobedience, or to prevent statements of agreement or support? Stack Overflow is a website whose content comes from *users*; how is it SO's responsibility to make sure that users never post anything that could get you in trouble with local laws around the world?

Comment: @NicolBolas Google and FB do indeed have that responsibility and take it seriously and execute it. For instance, FB takes down posts that violate India's laws against inciting racial hatred.

Comment: @torazaburo: "*Google and FB do indeed have that responsibility*", no they *choose* to do so. Why should SO choose to do so? And to what end? Which local laws/customs should they follow and which ones should they not care about? Every site that has user-created content has to deal with these questions. Why does SO's answer have to be identical to Google's?

Comment: @NicolBolas Google and FB "choose" to do so because not to choose to do so would entail violating local laws and risk getting shut down; it could also result in criminal claims against its executives. SO should also do so precisely to avoid getting shut down. They should follow all applicable local laws/customs, just like everyone else does. SO's answers should be similar, if not identical, to Google's, because presumably they have the same goals, which is not to be banned and thereby lose the revenue-generating stream of eyeballs the owners presumably care about.

Comment: @torazaburo I don't know if you've heard, but Google actually stopped operating in China *because* they got tired of following local laws there, so they withdrew and let themselves get blocked. On the other hand, pretty much any site would want to remove content inciting racial hatred because why would anyone want that on their site? That's an easy law to follow because it already violates any on-site policy they'd have against hate speech. That's not a country imposing their laws, that's a service acting on very basic policies that most services have.

Comment: @torazaburo: I'm sorry, but I cannot agree with that. To promote local laws to *global* status is to give global sovereignty to local entities. SO may serve content to those countries, but they do not have offices *within* those countries. And thus, they should not be subject to those laws, nor should SO willfully subject *themselves* to those laws. And "everyone else" doesn't follow every local law either. Do you see a rash of webforums banning people for posting characters that the Chinese government declares illegal? What about Wikipedia; do they ban the use of those characters?

Comment: No-one is talking about banning people, where did you get that?

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow changing the username means it is "taking a stance" on this topic, as it's a simple practical matter: 1.2 billion people may have trouble accessing SO because of this username. It is stupid and it sucks that this is the case, but it is what it is. We shouldn't go out of way to abide by China's demands, but at the same time *actively* trying to bait the Chinese probably isn't great, either, especially given the real practical impact it can have on a large portion of the planet's population.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker If you have a policy for one group of people, you have to have the policy for every other group of people, otherwise it *is* taking a stance. We can't go around saying that one group's needs matter more just because there's more of them. That's politics. As well, a user's intention behind a message simply is not relevant. That implies that a user who does not intend for something to happen is allowed to have the statement, even though it would cause the same problem. It can either be allowed or not allowed - there's no middle ground for "well, only if you're not intending this."

Comment: By that logic we should also [rename the necromancer badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334127/660921) @animuson, since it doesn't adhere to the "be nice" policy for a small group of people.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - the necromancer badge example does not apply here. This is basically a user initiated Denial of Service attack...

Comment: @torazaburo: "No-one is talking about banning people, where did you get that? "  Possibly [your answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349187/103167)  Are these not your words? "Therefore, members who choose to engage in political speech in their handles should be requested to change them. If they refuse to do so, ..., they would be banned or their account deleted."

Comment: @BenVoigt You appear to have been talking about banning people (simply) for posting certain characters. That is not-so-subtly different from what I described, which is banning in the context of generalized banning of people who fail to follow moderator guidance,

Comment: @torazaburo: Failure to follow moderator guidance is not a bannable offense.  Breaking a rule, particularly continuing to break it after the moderator has given you a chance to stop, could be.  Your answer suggests making a rule that some names are not allowed, for which the punishment for (repeatedly/protractedly) breaking is a ban or deletion.  But the consequences are associated to the rule violation, not to some misguided elevation of moderators to command instant obedience, and arguing otherwise is disingenuous.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't claim to understand the exact process by which people are banned by moderators or otherwise. My comment was based on my perhaps incorrect assumption that moderators can ban people for repeated failure to follow their guidance.

Comment: BTW the state of votes at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366163/can-i-use-images-such-as-from-tiananmen-square-protests-to-criticise-the-chinese appears to be overriding this answer

Comment: @Ciro the votes actually do not support your allegation

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier things changed after I made that comment.

Comment: calls to violence, like overth(fl)owing a president should it be tolerated? I reported such an exemple to be immediately censored, my comments removed because it seem that moderators are rather agree to such actions. But should it be a political moderation here?

Answer (score 57):

I say that we should do... nothing.

At its core, Stack Overflow is a website whose contents are defined by users. Now yes, we do try to keep things safe for work, and we do have a general Be Nice policy to deal with material that is offensive. But all our content comes from users.

And if you will be sanctioned for seeing certain phrases or images by the company you work for, the country you live in, or the culture you're a part of, then *any website* with user-defined content is not a safe place for you. Wikipedia, Reddit, and yes Stack Overflow too, you can encounter the banned material in all of these places.

It is not our responsibility to resolve this problem; that's *way* above our pay grade.

And yes, that means that a particular user can have a username that effectively makes it dangerous for you and those in your position to visit the site. But that's what it means to have user-defined content.

Stack Overflow cannot take responsibility to enforce the rules of your company/country/culture.

Comment: Even in the case that the user exploits this very matter and explicitly states that it's intention is deliberately putting another group of users in harm's way, or damaging them ( by making site inaccessible to them ) ?

Comment: @ObmerkKronen: 1) The user hasn't said that this is their intention. The user's profile makes no statement to that effect. 2) The user *cannot* harm other people. It's the society those people live in that is causing the harm.

Comment: 1)  Please refer to the second link I posted . It is cited there .  2 ) An action by one side towards another can have direct consequences on a third party . It's called collateral damage. and if it is pre-calculated and deliberated  - you can take off the word collateral.

Comment: The citizens of the country in question should avail themselves to their government-approved [QA site for programmers](https://segmentfault.com/). (I speculate that it's approved because a little link at the bottom leads me to the page with title translated "National Public Security Organs Internet Security Service Platform", and that `gov.cn` platform greets me with 'Your IP is not allowed to visit this website!'.  So it looks like the damage you are talking about is affecting mostly the foreigners there, but they are hardly innocent - they are in collusion with oppressive regime.

Comment: @artem: "*they are in collusion with oppressive regime.*" That's more of a political position to take. This is not and should not be about whether we can punish those who "are in collusion with oppressive regime". This should be about whether users are allowed to pick the usernames they want. About whether Stack Overflow has some responsibility for following local laws about user content. About whether SO can be "safe" for every viewer around the world.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen: "*An action by one side towards another can have direct consequences on a third party . It's called collateral damage.*" Let's say I agree with that statement. That still doesn't tell us whether it is SO's responsibility to *enforce* the laws and customs of every country/company/culture on everyone who uses this site. If one country bans a certain word or image, is it SO's responsibility to *enforce* that ban upon people who don't live in that country?

Comment: "live in that country"  is pretty vague condition for enforcing the ban. Are the subjects of Chinese government legally allowed to access banned content while they are outside China? Let's say you agree to enforce the ban for the users according to the laws of their country, but then the country demands you to ascertain the nationality (and identity, for that matter), of any user accessing your web site - will you agree? It can get political pretty fast.

Comment: Ironically, Wikipedia is mostly blocked in China. As you well said, any user-defined content (this is not censored) is not a safe place for ...

Comment: BTW the state of votes at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366163/can-i-use-images-such-as-from-tiananmen-square-protests-to-criticise-the-chinese appears to be overriding this answer

Answer (score 30):

As established in the links you've included in your first post, Stack Overflow's position until now has been that political *usernames and profiles* are acceptable. The question you raise - I think - is whether we should make an exception to censor political speech that some nation would retaliate against a user for even *seeing*, so that users in that nation don't endanger themselves by inadvertently viewing forbidden speech.

I admit that I have no idea exactly what nation or what political speech you're referring to; while restrictions on political speech are common throughout the world, I don't know of any country that punishes even the *accidental viewing* of forbidden political material, and since you've chosen not to tell us which country you work in, I will likely remain unenlightened about precisely what regime it is that implements such a totalitarian policy.

Regardless, I don't think Stack Overflow should modify a user's username on these grounds. Doing so would make them tools of a totalitarian state; we should not be censoring political material on behalf of governments just because they threaten to arbitrarily punish anyone within their borders who stumbles upon it if we don't. I sympathize with your circumstances, but if you wish to work in a country where accidentally stumbling across a forbidden phrase on the internet can literally put you in danger of violent retaliation from the state, then *you are going to need to take precautions for your own safety anyway*, no matter what Stack Overflow does. Those precautions should probably include not doing any browsing over an unencrypted connection and not visiting sites with user-generated content while you are in the room with anyone you don't trust. Even if we censored whatever particular username prompted you to ask this question, we can't prevent you from stumbling across something similar on Google.

Comment: @JoshCaswell as noted in the comments on the question, I don't think that China will imprison people for *reading* about the Tianenman Square massacre (or any of the other things it bans discussion of), let alone for stumbling across such material online *by accident*. Unless I'm missing something (and nobody has told me so yet), punishment for banned political speech in China is always applied to the speaker, not the listener. So while it seems that this *is* what the OP is talking about, I don't think it's true that she is "endangered".

Comment: @JoshCaswell at the time that I answered, I hadn't yet realised what user was being referred to, and had assumed that the country in question couldn't possibly be China; I am at least vaguely aware of China's censorship regime, as most people are. Thank you for the link anyway, though - I learned some more from it.

Comment: The links I provided , dealt with avatars and profiles. I might be wrong - but  - and correct me if I am wrong  - I do not recall seeing a specific resolution about user display name ( which appears in more cases than the rest ) .  In regards to the links I provided , an accepted answer cited _"explicit attacks on a particular group of people"_  and _"each case would need to be examined on its own merits_" . I think that your own statement of not knowing the territory or the  username might be of influence in your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately - There is no_ "accidentally stumbling across a forbidden phrase"_ . and google does not work in that territory. Another issue that I feel I need to stress again - I am not asking community to _"censor political speech that some nation would retaliate against a user for even seeing,"_ . my point is the community allowing one user to exploit that known consequence in order to deliberately ( by its own statement ) harm other users . In that context . the whole political discussion is mute .

Comment: _that political usernames and profiles are acceptable._ Nope. My display name at some point used to be "Visa is Racism", because I think asking citizens of a whole country for visa is a kind of racism. I was contacted by SO and asked to change the name.

Comment: @Shahbaz - exactly . because choosing when the "apolitical" becomes irrelevant is in direct relation where the community influence lives and what the accepted culture is there . ( I assume the visa issue was US related - and I do not express any support for that or to any political issue on a software Q&A site ) .

Comment: @ObmerkKronen The uncomfortable truth is SO gets political when it is closer to the [home country of SO as a company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand).

Comment: @Shahbaz I'm sorry to hear that; such an act by the mods contradicts the policy established at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231362/200582 and serves no purpose that I can see. I'd encourage you to post on Meta about your own case (including disclosing the content of whatever communication you had with the mods) and to restore your username to what it was. We're not supposed to be in the business of suppressing political speech that other users don't like.

Comment: @Shahbaz they asked you to remove such a tame username? Interesting! Was there a meta thread I can look into?

Comment: @Shahbaz - To clarify, you were contacted by a moderator acting on their own, not an SE employee. That moderator changed your name based on their personal judgment. What is and is not acceptable in a username has been the subject of a lot of debate among moderators, and we don't all agree. We've been given guidance in the past that if a username [is becoming a distraction, it should be changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267368/are-political-avatars-and-profiles-ok/267370#comment70688_267370), so how we handle this does vary from moderator to moderator.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen All speech is potentially political. The choice to allow or prohibit _any_ individual statement, on any topic, is political. This is because "politicalness" is not a property of the speech, it is a property of politics, and there is nothing to prevent unaccountable governments from unilaterally declaring certain speech forbidden. Stack Overflow cannot both permit open public discussion and ban all content that repressive governments prohibit. The solution I would recommend is for you to IP and DNS block Stack Overflow **yourself**, preventing accidental direct access.

Comment: @CiroSantilli709大抓捕六四事件法轮功 That was quite a few years ago, I don't believe I can dig up any info on that.

Comment: @ClementCherlin Stack Overflow does **not** permit open public discussion. It permits open public discussion **on programming topics**.

Comment: @torazaburo I believe you have misunderstood. I never said, nor do I believe, that Stack Overflow permits open public discussion of _all_ topics. I said it permits open public discussion, which it does. Stack Overflow cannot permit **open public discussion of programming**, while banning all content that repressive governments prohibit. For example, consider the topic of how to best write a VPN to bypass a particular repressive government's firewall. That's on-topic for SO, politically charged, and very likely illegal in that government's jurisdiction.

Comment: @ClementCherlin While I agree with you that the particular content discussed in this question shouldn't be censored, and also agree with you that Stack Overflow shouldn't censor all content that is banned by any government anywhere (which is in itself a strawman that nobody here has proposed), I still feel inclined to point out that Stack Overflow doesn't permit "open public discussion of programming" as you and torazaburo suggest, and never has. We have a pretty ruthless system of censorship of content that doesn't meet our standards, through the closure and deletion systems.

Comment: @MarkAmery I don't mean SO = 4chan. By "open public discussion" I mean **discussions** that are **open** to full **public** participation, a definition which SO meets. Open: Not closed. An invitation-only online discussion is closed, even if the archives are made public. Public: Not private. An online discussion with no public archives is private in that only participants see the messages. SO is not private, and participation is not limited to only those who agree to follow the censorship rules of _every government in the world simultaneously_, which is the topic of discussion.

Comment: BTW the state of votes at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366163/can-i-use-images-such-as-from-tiananmen-square-protests-to-criticise-the-chinese might contradict this answer

Answer (score 17):

If you are asking "what can I and other users do to protect ourselves against this username?", perhaps a Greasemonkey script or the equivalent can filter it out for you. Or, perhaps develop a dedicated browser plugin to filter it out.

If you are asking "what I can and other users to with regards to Stack sites overall?", I recommend supplying the following to The Powers That Be:

- Details of the username
- Reasons why the username causes risks to site users (e.g., against the law, prone to vigilante reprisals)
- Evidence of the nature of the specific harm that comes to people viewing the proscribed username (e.g., death, injury, imprisonment, deportation)
- Evidence of the nature of the specific harm that comes to sites that publish proscribed words (e.g., site blocks)

IOW, make your case that this username is risky for site visitors and, perhaps, to the site itself.

I'm not sure if Meta is the right place for that, or whether the [contact-us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) link is a better option. My instinct is to use the contact-us link, as posting this material to Meta might merely exacerbate the issue.

---

In terms of what the response should be, IMHO, that's a decision to be made by the owners and operators of Stack Exchange, Inc. Given a specific scenario (username and evidence of potential damage stemming from that username), they need to decide whether to:

- Replace the username
- Leave the username in place, but flag it as risky, then implement site solutions to reduce the risk to innocent site visitors, such as:

  - Mark all risky usernames as "redacted", with a tooltip showing the real name
  - Offering a "risk aversion" setting in your profile, where for certain settings risky usernames are redacted, with either a fixed default setting or one derived based on where you are visiting from
  - Applying these sorts of technical countermeasures across the board (i.e., users never see risky usernames) or on a per-region basis (i.e., users in Region X do not see risky usernames tied to risks from Region X but would see risky usernames from other regions)
- Leave the username in place with no countermeasures, as they do not believe that the harm that it may cause is worth the cost to the freedom of expression
- Some other possibility that I am not thinking of

---

Whether any given specific scenario rises to the level warranting action would depend on the details. It appears that many people do not feel that this specific situation warrants action. IMHO, there is nothing intrinsically wrong with that position. However, **there is a distinct difference between "this scenario does not warrant action" and "there is never a scenario that warrants action"**. The OP tried to draw that distinction.

So, let's examine a different scenario, [one that Pekka 웃 pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349131/political-user-display-name-what-should-i-do?cb=1#comment472716_349131).

Suppose the following series of events occurs:

- Somebody creates and popularizes a Stack Overflow account whose username is considered to be [defamatory to Thai royalty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A8se_majest%C3%A9_in_Thailand)
- Some Thai prosecutor decides that software developers are "undesirables", finds out about this Stack Overflow account, and files charges against a number of Thai Stack Overflow users who can be demonstrated to have engaged with the defamatory user (e.g., participated in questions/answers/comments/chats that the defamatory user also participated in)
- Thai judges agree that participating in discussions containing a defamatory name constitutes lèse-majesté, sentencing these Stack Overflow users for 3-15 years imprisonment per count
- Thai officials [block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A8se_majest%C3%A9_in_Thailand#Internet_blocking_measures) Stack Overflow... after the prosecutions have been completed
- This makes the news by one means or another, so that we are aware of these events

IMHO, this scenario is within the realm of possibility. Almost by definition, it would be legal within the Thai legal framework<sup>1</sup>. For that matter, it is not wrong, depending upon one's thoughts regarding the law in question.

So, in this scenario, we have otherwise-innocent Stack Overflow users being imprisoned, simply because they participated in the site in the same areas as somebody else who "picked a fight".
Perhaps some people who might not want Stack Overflow to take action in the OP's scenario might be more willing for action in this case, since there is demonstrable harm coming to Stack Overflow users, rather than theoretical potential harm.

---

Some have said that this isn't "our" decision. If by "our" one means most of the people participating in this Meta question, I agree completely. When things rise to this level, IMHO the only parties who really get a vote are the owners and operators of Stack Exchange, Inc., working in conjunction with the people providing evidence of the problem and Stack Exchange's legal counsel.

All that I am hoping for is clarity — whether from moderators or higher authorities — as to how to report this sort of issue and what sorts of information to supply (as a replacement for my proposed list).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>IANATLNDIPOOTVATDNCLA (I am not a Thai lawyer, nor do I play one on TV, and this does not constitute legal advice)</sub>

Comment: "*So, in this scenario, we have otherwise-innocent Stack Overflow users being imprisoned, simply because they participated in the site in the same areas as somebody else who "picked a fight".*" But that could have happened on Wikipedia, or *any other website* with user-created content. If you are subject to conditions such that conviction-by-association is a thing, then you have to take upon yourself to avoid going to places online where your associations can have consequences that you don't want. You can't ask site owners to police their entire userbase just for you.

Comment: It should also be noted that, in the specific case cited here, a Greasemonkey script won't resolve the issue. It still transmits the incriminating characters, even if it doesn't display them, so it can still cause problems with ISPs retaliating for downloading illegal materials. If a filtering solution is to be effective, it would have to be done at the source, server-side.

Comment: @NicolBolas: "But that could have happened on Wikipedia, or any other website with user-created content" -- this is not Wikipedia. "You can't ask site owners to police their entire userbase just for you" -- it is up to the site owners to decide what to do. Unless I misunderstand your role here, you have as much ownership stake here as I do, and I have none at all. With respect to Greasemonkey, it helps insofar as it limits the number of people who see the defamatory material, but I agree it is far from a perfect solution.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It stands to reason that there are websites that *are* safe for Thai, Chinese, and others to visit. So, in actual point of fact, you totally *can* ask a site owner to take steps to make their site safe. Depending on the ease of complying, they may do so quickly, with careful consideration, with a *lot* of careful consideration, reluctantly refuse, or laugh in your face. Conflating all sites that have UGC together is not helpful; SE in general is quite successful despite (or because) it is far more heavily-moderated than most UGC sites. So it is one of the best candidates for this.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Wikipedia is even more heavy in their moderation than SO. Do they restrict users from having usernames with such things in them? Do they enforce local laws about banned words/phrases?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Now that you mention it, [WP actually *does* have a policy that user pages can't have "material that is likely to bring the project into disrepute, or which is likely to give widespread offense (e.g. pro-pedophilia advocacy)."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:User_pages#What_may_I_not_have_in_my_user_pages.3F). The extent to which that applies to cases like this one where the disrepute is somewhat localized I don't know, and it's unlikely even most active editors really know the ins and outs, but it seems plausible enough. Plus, that's for userpages, not even names.

Comment: @NathanTuggy The [Wikipedia title blacklist](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Title_blacklist) applies to usernames as well as page names. (Some of the entries, like the ones flagged as "newaccountonly", _only_ apply to usernames.) Most of their username blocks are aimed at spammers, impersonation attempts, and persistent vandals, but there are also some blocks which specifically target offensive words or phrases.

Comment: I think it's important to note that your "suggested responses" that you believe would actually "fix" the situation are not available.  StackOverflow displays its content under a CC BY-SA license granted by the content authors. **That license requires attribution.**  StackOverflow cannot alter or remove the attribution *unless an anonymization request is made by the author*.  It would be possible to stop displaying any content from the affected users altogether, or to visitors from certain areas.  When the trolling was done using brand new accounts, there's no problem.  Here, it's not so easy.

Comment: @BenVoigt: good point about attribution.  Would displaying a username as user12345 that still links to their profile be sufficient attribution, as a way for SO to do server-side munging?  (Possibly configurable so certain users could get SO to not use some display-names.  Or possibly just system-wide by squashing and locking out that user's display name, leaving only the underlying number.  They could still say whatever they want in their profile page, but users in censored countries should probably only check profile pages via VPN.) IDK if this is a good idea, but maybe legal and technically

Answer (score 13):

I think Stack Overflow has an obligation to protect its users, also from *their* governments.
That doesn't necessarily mean protesting on their behalf.

I'll try reframe the issue: the user **exploits the popularity of Stack Overflow** to protest and promote a cause. This makes Stack Overflow a tool in a *cat-and-mouse* game with the Chinese censorship.

The problem, as the OP called it, is *collateral damage*. It is very easy (for most of us) to say "freedom of speech is the cornerstone of human rights, let him do as he pleases" - but it's important to remember none of us is paying the price. 
Not everyone is so privileged. There *is* collateral damage. By allowing this username we are creating friction, and **we are placing Chinese citizens, residents, students, and even tourists at the front-line of this protest**.
Having even minor contact with this user - which anyone can do, not knowingly - can have severe consequences: You could be denied entry to China, your visa could be revoked and you could be deported, you could be arrested, or *just* investigated.
This can ruin lives.
It is not limited to China, of course. People could be [denied access to the US after a phone search](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/2017/04/10/british-visitors-us-may-asked-passwords-phone-contacts-airports/). Contact with a user with a provocative name is a good-enough excuse.

In my opinion, such user names are inappropriate. Stack Overflow is *not* a place for demonstrations. Similar messages would have been removed *in minutes* as off-topic if posted in answers or comments. The idea that just the username textbox is entitled to free speech is a little silly, to be honest.

In general, **the level of leeway each field in the profile gets should be *inversely proportional* to its exposure**. A user name is very exposed, and it makes sense it would have stricter limitations.

So where is the line? Like they say, I'll know it when I see it. In this case it looks more like an exploit of the username field.

---

Disclaimer - Free speech is awesome and every single person on earth should enjoy it.

Comment: Please note: I'm don't agree with my answer 100%.

Comment: Also, if that is relevant, I live in Israel. My icon currently has the flag on India because of reasons.

Comment: I didn't go into other exploits of the username field. Imagine a user called *"Alex php java javascript python mysql c# android ios"*.

Comment: This. People are **actively endangered**. If I could bounty MSO answers, I would bounty this, just to draw more attention to the fact that there is a very real danger to some of our users.

Answer (score 11):

Firstly, I am sympathetic towards how this has/could/will affect yourself and others who live/work with the "regime" in question (to the curious, it is China, but as the OP requested, I intend to answer in a generic way)

But, I also believe that censoring this username is the same as making concessions to the regime in question, which, in my mind, is the same as supporting it, whereas doing nothing is neutral (which, even though this isn't a "political" site, is a questionable stance anyway, in my opinion).

Censoring this username in particular will solve one small problem in a sea of problems around freedom of information and opinion for the affected people, while essentially giving that government "control" over the moderation of stack overflow, not just for it's own citizens, but for those of the entire world.  I think this is unacceptable, and this is more of a political message than just ignoring the username.

I think the intentions of the user are irrelevant, honestly.  What if the user had a "banned" phrase in their username for some other purpose?  Would it still be okay to change that username?  What if tomorrow 20 other governments enacted similar policies for 100 other "banned" phrases?  Would it still be okay then?

I understand this is a problem for you, and many others.  But the one who has created the problem is the government banning the phrase, even if the user is purposefully goading them.  You are only suggesting action be taken upon the user because it is much easier and more convenient than getting the government to change.

I don't agree that the username should be altered in any way, but to maybe help with solving the actual problems:

I think you and anyone else in this situation has to come to terms with the reality of dealing with the kind of government that would make this a problem in the first place.  You can choose not to do business with them, or live there (obviously that's a huge effect on your life), or you can take whatever precautions you can, just like you would have to for a million other websites when you are in that country.

Proxies/VPNs as you mentioned can help you.
For cases where clients are snooping over your shoulder, perhaps some custom adblock rules can help you (you can block with css rules).

Comment: The bigger question is weather a software related  Q&A site should even have these occurrences to begin with , and should they be allowed . the scope of this site is totally unrelated to politics. so why involve personal or political crusades in it ? doing that will only leave space to other eventual debates which result in comments and answers based on political and / or cultural views . ( see other [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349131/political-user-display-name-what-should-i-do/349163#comment472831_349163) )

Comment: @ObmerkKronen one rationale is that such profiles punishing oppressive regimes with worse IT, thus encouraging them to become more open. The counter argument is that maybe oppression will only end when certain IT level is reached.

Comment: in other words.. punish people who have nothing to do with the problem other than where they are living/were born.

Comment: @KevinB The government of China is punishing people living in China. Stack Overflow is not responsible for the rules that the oppressive, unaccountable government of China puts in place for its citizens, nor is Stack Overflow punishing those citizens. Let's not reverse causality here. The Chinese government bans its citizens from visiting any site that contains any text that is in any way critical of the Chinese government. Stack Overflow can endorse this censorship by becoming a Chinese government censor-by-proxy, or say "those laws suck and we're not going to enforce them ourselves."

Comment: @ClementCherlin Well, no, i'm not saying SO is punishing these users, the user using said names that are known to cause this problem are purposefully, knowingly, forcing users who may or may not have any interest in protesting said censorship into protesting it or giving up SO use. That's what i see as wrong. If you want to protest, protest. but don't infringe on the innocent.

Comment: BTW the state of votes at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366163/can-i-use-images-such-as-from-tiananmen-square-protests-to-criticise-the-chinese might contradict this answer

Answer (score 9):

I assume this is about a certain user who has certain phrases in his username to "offend" the government of the People's Republic of China and bait them in to blocking Stack Overflow through The Great Firewall.

This is not the first question asked about this person's choice of username. In your question you link to some other meta-posts asked about this, and in the past the responses have more or less boiled down to a shrug. I've always felt this was a mistake.

We can't and shouldn't remove every little thing that someone might find offensive, but if it's effectively "Not Safe For Work" for 1.3 billion people – no matter how silly and oppressive the reasons – then we may want to consider taking action. Especially if this action is quick, painless, and has no consequence to the normal functioning of the site. We're here to provide quality Q&A, not to make political statements about various governments.

Stack Overflow is a Q&A site designed to be as free from useless distractions as reasonably possible, and it succeeds remarkably well at ths.
Users get a fair amount of leeway with their profiles - it is their "personal space" - but this should end when it starts to interfere with the Q&A part of the site, which is exactly what this person's username is doing by disrupting access to 1.3 billion people.
We can have long and probably interesting discussions about whether this is moral or correct or ethical, but Stack Overflow is not the place for those sort of discussions.

Comment: I find the "Not Safe For Work" analogy to be interesting. Obviously, different cultures have different ideas of what is "Safe for work", so taking a lowest-common-denominator approach is not unreasonable. We consider NSFW to be sex, violence, or needless profanity. At the same time, I have a problem with extending the NSFW policy to more arbitrary things. Particularly when it means that we are enforcing the rules of governmental censorship. Perhaps the more general question is whether usernames should be allowed to have political speech at all.

Comment: @NicolBolas - I think you hit the precise point in this comment. Is being _"apolitical"_ means to _"allow all"_ , or "forbid all" ? . Another issue is that  i understand that _"enforcing the rules of governmental censorship"_ sound bad to all , but in that context, does _"helping another X political cause which one think is right"_ any different ? apolitical is a two-way ( dark and confusing ) street ...

Comment: _"We're here to provide quality Q&A, not to make political statements about various governments"_ . can not summarize my feelings better.

Comment: A profile page is just that and doesn't have anything to do with discussions nor technicalities. I find hard to believe a "Great Firewall" is incapable of blocking a single URL (or a handful of them). Now, the username will leak for pages upon pages on the site, that's another issue.

Comment: @brasofilo with HTTPS, the firewall can't see which page is transmitted. See [Are URLs viewed during HTTPS transactions to one or more websites from a single IP distinguishable?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4388/are-urls-viewed-during-https-transactions-to-one-or-more-websites-from-a-single) (I don't know whether the Chinese firewall is playing MiTM with fake certificates, that might help.)

Comment: For someone claiming "Stack Overflow is not the place for those sort of discussions", you take a rather **strong** pro-censorship stance: "no matter how [...] oppressive the reasons – then we may want to consider taking action". You also seem to equate "NSFW" with "not accepted by XX regime", and, lastly, you imply that saying certain things equates to "disrupting access to 1.3 billion people". Please note that no one here is disrupting access to anyone.

Answer (score 9):

I think we're ignoring the elephant in the room here.

The profile of the user in question explains, in extensive detail, that the purpose of some of the content in their username is *explicitly* to make it difficult for Chinese users to view the site. There are political aspects to it, of course -- but the phrases they've included in their username are chosen specifically because they are likely to trigger blocks by the Chinese [GFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall).

Unfortunately, based on the OP's narrative, it appears that this disruption may have been successful.

The solution is simple -- forcibly remove that content from their username. Their username already contains a perfectly reasonable given name, which is clearly how they expect themselves to be addressed. Names should *identify users*, not be a platform for advertisement or disruption.

Comment: So you propose to outlaw terms on SO based on the GFW filter? The solution here is for OP to apply for government approved VPN access without any filters.

Comment: @le_m No, I'm proposing an action specific to this user. No reason to make this any broader than necessary.

Comment: @le_m - I agree that censorship is an issue that should be treated with care - but I don't see any value in encouraging behaviour that segregates entire countries. Allowing the user to keep this username adds **no value to the site**, and such I don't see why anyone here should feel strongly about allowing it...

Comment: @shadow Taking action against a single user that is not backed by a general policy that applies to everyone equally seems not right to me. However, we can't and don't want to make it a general policy that GFW terms are forbidden. That's why I am not yet convinced by duskwuff's answer.

Comment: @le_m: I think the point duskwuff is making is that the user in question has declared an intent to *attack*, effectively weaponizing Stack Overflow towards a political end. There's a case to be made that this constitutes a distinct scenario from someone who just so happens to use those characters in their name.

Comment: I would heartily agree if this was in his `about me` section - but this is his username. If he was openly insulting chinese (or american, german, whatever) culture in said username, people would find it offensive and report it. I don't see why targeting innocent chinese users is any different to that. As @NicolBolas said - why are we allowing the weaponisation of stack overflow?

As a side - it's quite likely that this user **can't** report the user because the GFW probably doesn't allow him to :P

Comment: @NicolBolas Precisely. The user's intent to disrupt the site is what's important here. It shouldn't take a specific rule to recognize an attempt to disrupt the site as being undesirable, and to take action against it.

Comment: Good point. But to OP it doesn't make any difference whether there is intent behind a username or not - the consequences for OP are the same. OP would have posted the same question here if the user in question would not act intentionally. If that were the case, you would accept it then? I think we should find a general guideline on how to deal with such cases.

Comment: @Shadow: One can [link to a user profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1594286) without citing the callsign.

Comment: @le_m - If someone wrote a script that was DOSing stack overflow (somehow successfully), would we ignore it because they "weren't doing it intentionally"? A person's username name is of no consequence to the usefulness of this site, nor the information it holds. That's why I think that people who are saying to just leave it are overreacting (underreacting?). I feel like they are just shouting 'freedom' for the sake of it.

Comment: @le_m "I think we should find a general guideline…" I disagree. No need to generalize from a one-off issue.

Answer (score 8):

I was once a programmer for a site for knitting hobbyists. Actually the site was just a bunch of forums about knitting techniques, patterns, machines etc. It was very popular, with a friendly, constantly growing community. All this till one user posted a very political comment on one of the forums. The owner asked me what to do. Being a very tolerant person myself I told him to do nothing, arguing that our audience is not so interested in politics, as in knitting, and the issue will die by itself.

God, how I was wrong. In a very short time all forums were discussing politics, no hint of former friendliness remained, very active and contributing users started to leave, and despite my efforts to set filters, despite owners' efforts to moderate content, the site was ruined and it took about one full year to bring the order back. The site was never so popular afterward and died two years later.

I know SO is much bigger, much more mature, much more stable, still, I am worried.

Comment: As the links in the question show, it's been several years already. You may also be interested in [If you're gonna talk politics, you must respect those who disagree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289398)

Comment: This is a far reach example from the situation we have here. We *don't* allow active political discussion in questions, answers, or comments on our site and those types of discussions are quickly deleted because they have no place in active content. We're talking about something that is limited to display names and profiles (and dare I say chat, because I don't follow chat that much). Yours is a situation where they effectively didn't bother to moderate *any* part of the site and let political discussion take over. That's not going to happen here.

Comment: @animuson Hypocrisy, much? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand

Comment: @Flot2011 The CEO of SO gave the whole site the finger earlier this year when he decided to suddenly start talking politics on meta, ignoring all the site rules. Despite his attempts to ruin the site, SO is still active. All that was achieved with the post was a massive loss of trust in the SO management and SO employees.

Comment: So even tight-knit communities fall apart...

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply, SO is not a forum for political speech.

If a portion of a post were political speech, if would be edited out. If an entire post were political speech, it would be deleted, if not by members, then by a moderator when flagged. Political speech remains political speech when part of a handle. Members are forced to read that political speech every time they view a post, or even on the main page if a post from that person happens to make it there.

Permitting political speech as part of handles thus interferes with my ability and that of all members to use the site as it was intended.

It is at this point that meta readers typically trot out the logical fallacy that we cannot possibly "censor" political speech in handles because it involves human judgment. However, many aspects of SO, including moderator decisions, involve human judgment. If people disagree with the human judgments, there are ways to appeal such judgments. In this case, the judgment could be reserved for SE personnel, if we do not think moderators can handle the job.

Therefore, members who choose to engage in political speech in their handles should be requested to change them. If they refuse to do so, just as in the case of any member who refuses to heed any moderator suggestions, they would be banned or their account deleted.

The simple fact that political speech is off-topic at SO, wherever it occurs, is perfectly adequate as a reason for taking such steps. It is not "censorship"; no-one is being denied their right to "free speech", as if that misunderstood notion applied to SO in the first place. It is merely upholding the standards and guidelines of the site.

However, it is certainly worth also taking into the account the points made by the OP, that such political speech in handles not only violates site guidelines, but also can actively cause harm to other members and/or their companies, and eventually cause harm to SO as a whole if it results in the entire site being banned in some region, depriving all the budding programmers there of its benefit, not to mention depriving SO of the revenue deriving from their eyeballs.

Not allowing political speech in handles does not require entangling ourselves in issues over whether such speech is or is not offensive to or banned by any particular government, and whether we like that government or its policies, or whether SO should or should not be engaged in bending down to such policies. It merely requires recognizing that political speech is off-topic at SO.

Comment: Except when the entire post is political speech, the members *do* delete it, and then the moderators *undelete* it.  Repeatedly.

Comment: *The simple fact that political speech is off-topic at SO, wherever it occurs* - is there a source confirming that this rule applies to usernames? Also, it is not about political speach but about any speach deemed harmful by he CCP including historical facts, religious beliefs etc etc. Where to draw the line?

Comment: Apparently, [SO _is_ a forum for political speech.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand) (Still agree with this answer, though)

Comment: @Cerbrus this seems to hold only for those who are "more equal than others"

Comment: @Cerbrus to be pedantic, it has finally been admitted by an employee that that post is "not considered a good, on-topic question for this site". It exists solely because the rules don't apply to... that person.

Comment: Here's a question: who decides that certain speech is "political"? It's easy to deal with it in obvious cases, but if you translate the phrases in the person's username, they are not *a priori* political statements. They only become political because of the actions of a particular government. Which means it now becomes possible to have a username that is otherwise valid, but becomes political because of someone else. Imagine a user who named himself MAGA, in 2012. That was perfectly a-political back then, but now it means something different. What should be done about that?

Comment: Nothing, until it is reported by a user and proven to cause problems. such as with this case.

Comment: I have a friend who works at ISIS @NicolBolas: "**I**nnovative **S**olutions **I**n **S**pace" (obviously this company and its name predate the Islamic State ISIS). While there may certainly be cases like this, I don't really see how that really applies to this user or his username. Just because in *some other cases* it might be difficult to say what is or isn't political doesn't really say a whole lot about this case.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'd be interested in an example of moderators undeleting posts considered to be political speech.

Comment: @torazaburo: Ok, they reopened it before the community had a chance to finish the deletion process.  But here a prime example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/269992/revisions  And another, also repeated shutdown by the community, forced open by moderators: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/297859/revisions  And another: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/342440/revisions

Comment: *they would be banned or their account deleted.* - no need for that, unless they keep posting politics in their posts.  Just squash their display name so it displays as user12345.

Answer (score 1):

Note: The text below originated in an edit the OP made to their post. As the edit's content seemed more appropriate as an answer than as part of the question, the text has been moved to this answer and marked as a community wiki.

---

I want to share a mail that I just got, related to this question.
It is , IMHO , a little extreme and radical - even belligerent - but I think it has an important point of view.

[...] THIS IS NOT MY VIEW NOR DESIRE.

> Hi.
>
> I just saw your question [link] on SE , and got your mail from [ Link
>   to local-language Forum ]  where you had a profile.
>
> I do not want to intervene or  post a radical answer ( read below )
>   simply because I am a very passive user of SE,  and do not really
>   contribute to the site due to the amateur nature of my programming
>   skills. I mostly read .
>
> I do however in a similar situation like yourself, being a foreigner
>   in [ Territory ] for over 15 years. - and I have , like you,  saw the username
>   in question, and aslo had outages,  but was always passive also in
>   that regards .
>
> But - I must say , you are approaching it all wrong .
>
> When I arrived to [ Territory ] from my own western developed country, my
>   views and positions were exactly like all the other answers . [ Territory ]
>   is oppressive regime - fight for the people's power etc . But after
>   living here for 15 years - I know better.  what I try to say is that
>   you are wasting your energy trying to get US / EU dwelling citizens
>   see your point from the comfort of their securities . A feasted person
>   would never understand the hungry .
>
> On the same time, I am quite sure that if  someone would change their
>   user name to a direct insult on a very known and controversial
>   monotheist god ( that already provoked some scandals ) - the
>   community will kick in and could not retain it's integrity . Especially if it > would be in some middle-eastern character set.
>
> What I propose is a whole different approach. 
>   Don't fight it - embrace it .
>
> Let us call all of the users we know inside [ Territory ], Foreigners and
>   [ Natives ] alike to change our usernames to the exact one of that
>   original user . I am sure that we could easily get a few thousands in
>   a less than a week. I will even provide my own proxy infrastructure to
>   do so . In a matter of days the [ NAME OF FIREWALL SYSTEM ] will kick into action and SE will
>   be probably banned and loose all their traffic and millions of hits from [ Territory ]
>
> Sometimes you have to deflect the damage away from you , and towards
>   the other part , in order to resolve a matter .
>
> The other option is to make a direct complaint in [ Territory ] to the
>   competent authorities, with the predictable result of banning the
>   whole SE network . Probably also the the banning of this one
>   individual from [ TERRITORY ] and possibly all others with same real name . I
>   would not go that way, but I would love to see SE fight on the same
>   arena where mammoths like google, facebook, twitter and even the US
>   government has already lost .
>
> Like I said , It would be counter-productive to post this on SE as an
>   answer . Will only drag spiralling arguments , downvotes avalanche and
>   more irrelevant debate about freedom and rights .
>
> If you want  help in this matter ,please [ Censured :-)  ]

Comment: Do you have permission to reproduce this email?

Comment: *It would be counter-productive to post this on SE as an answer* - I agree. It promotes a concerted effort to get SO banned in China with the implied goal to pressure Stack Exchange Inc. into applying CCP censorship rules here - or face economic losses. Let's honor the author's wish and not put this up as an answer here.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Is that question addressed to me, or to the OP? As the answer states, all I did was move some text from the OP's question into a community wiki answer, giving appropriate credit, which is permitted by SO's content license. Whether or not the OP had permission to post this in the first place is their concern. Either the OP or the person who originally sent the email is certainly free to request that this answer be removed if they so desire. (And of course, the SO community is free to upvote, downvote, or delete this answer, as per usual.)

Comment: @Ajedi32: To whoever. Actually, since you republished it, it became your concern :) You can't alleviate your responsibility just because somebody else had already published it elsewhere first. _"Either the OP or the person who originally sent the email is certainly free to request that this answer be removed if they so desire."_ That is not how it works. You get permission first, and don't put it up if you don't have permission.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Says who? As I noted, [content on SO is licensed](https://stackexchange.com/legal#3SubscriberContent) under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license, which permits me to copy content from it freely without asking the original author. If the OP or sender of the original email want to claim otherwise, they're welcome to sue me. (Or, you know, just ask politely and I'll remove the post, as I previously stated.)

Comment: @Ajedi32: As the original content was actually copyright by default, the OP had no legal authority to grant the CC by SA 3.0 licence to the content, thus you are not able to avail yourself of its terms. Your argument is like, if I videotaped a movie in the cinema and put it on Stack Overflow in hex-pair form, would I be able to take that and share it still futher? No of course not :)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition By posting the email here the OP has implicitly asserted that they have a legal right to do so (per SO's terms of service). I have no way of verifying one way or the other whether they're correct in that assertion (nor am I qualified to do so, as I'm not a lawyer), and frankly I don't really care either way. Again, if the copyright holder of this email wants to assert that _I_ am infringing on their copyright by posting it here they're certainly welcome to do so (at which point I'll remove it regardless of whether I believe I'm actually infringing or not).

Comment: @Ajedi32: Okay, then in that case I'm asking the OP. Look I don't really care who's at fault; the point is that this appears to be a private email published on the internet without permission.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Cool. Let me know what you find out.

Answer (score -4):

Your question discusses the negative consequences that this person's choice of username has for you and various other people. And yet, you chose to do business in a totalitarian regime, knowing full well the potential consequences of that choice. Now you have to face up to those consequences, and you're finding them unpalatable.

Well, tough.

Stack Overflow isn't responsible for protecting its users from the results of their decisions. The problem here is the regime you've chosen to take money from for your work, not the user whose name offends said regime's political sensibilities.

EDIT for anyone who is downvoting me because they somehow think I support censorship: whether I do or do not isn't relevant to the question asked. The issue is between the asker and the government of the country in question; it isn't Stack Overflow's problem or responsibility in any way, shape or form.

Comment: The OP's situation, and what we think of their business choices, doesn't really matter in this discussion though - the same thing could happen to any of the 1.38 billion people who had no choice when becoming subject to that totalitarian regime (with possibly much more severe consequences than a cancelled contract). Not saying that means we should self-censor everything that could offend said regime, or any other regime... but the "well, tough" argument doesn't seem pertinent to this discussion

Comment: You chose to do business in a totalitarian regime... Wow. Isn't it incredible how people can just completely disregard entire countries so flippantly... or are you seriously implying that people who happen to reside in such a country **deserve** to be banned from whole sites just because a specific user on that site think they're funny?

Comment: Wow. You think that the people residing in that country should have access to the resources provided by this site, while the government of that country blatantly disregards basic principles of the culture that built the internet, including this site. Web exists only because people have the ability to freely express themselves without asking for permission, and without fearing retribution for being non-conforming.

Comment: @shadow I think what he's saying is that these users should be complaining to the government when they do get banned. It makes sense, SE has no obligation to respect the laws of totalitarian governments.

Comment: @shadow Please provide evidence that the user in question thinks they're "funny". From what I can see from their profile, they are completely serious about the issue of censorship. The method they've taken to confront it is a novel and problematic one, but it is obviously having results (hence this question), which means it's achieved more than most of us have in that regard.

Comment: @artem I have no idea where you got that from; my answer neither condemns nor condones the behaviour of that country, for the reason that my opinions of said behaviour aren't relevant to the issue at hand.

Comment: do I understand correctly that one would also better abstain of buying and using stuff made in that country? Because money paid for it would support the regime over there and those who decided to do business with it, wouldn't it

Answer (score -7):

I feel that I can't take a stand on either side of this issue. A user should be allowed to express themselves but one should also not be excommunicated because of the actions of another user. 
I think the best case scenario would be a server side script allowing users to block users that they find offensive or similar. The downside would be losing valuable information that user has to contribute but in a situation such as this both parties could use SO without feeling oppressed.

Comment: In what sense does asking someone to remove/change a username which is blatantly offensive to some people, and which is harming other people, constitute "excommunication"?

Comment: Is _"I'm the next Hitler"_ as username covered in freedom of expression? Or is that just trolling? (Disclaimer: that's an example. I am in no way the next... ugh, no.)

Comment: @Cerbrus I KNEW IT!!!!!!

Comment: Instead of blocking the user, have their name display as user12345 for you (i.e. ignore their display name, treat it as if they never set one).  It might even let you reply to their comments with the right user-number, although it would look confusing to them and everyone else.