# The easily accessible information on how to help non-English speakers use Stack Overflow is outdated

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, help-center, languages

According to [this official blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/). The policy for when a user asks a non-English question is as follows:

> Users who post non-English questions should be gently directed to programming forums in their own language. Community should form around the gravity of native human languages. (see: Chinatown, Little Italy, etc.) Feel free to post links to appropriate human language-specific resources.

However, I recently discovered via an interaction on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046718/jquery-d%C3%BAvida-append-e-appendto-injetar-html#comment75119853_44046718) that there are official Stack Overflows for non-English speakers. This is something I never would have discovered from [SO's help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

With a bit more research, I found [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/01/08/year-in-review-2014/) which announces the releases of [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) and [Portugese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) Stack Overflow. However, I recently found that there's an official [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) Stack Overflow as well, which I definitely would not have found unless I was actively looking for it.

Shouldn't it be much more apparent to users who review questions that these official sites even exist? If anything, I feel **a list of links to every supported Stack Overflow language site** should be made readily available somewhere on the official help page for when a user asks a non-English question.

Comment: There are plenty of pages in the Help but only a few can be edited  by mods as is explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259920/158100). What would be the best place and why and how would non-english visitors find those pages?

Comment: @rene however all pages are editable by the CMs/Devs - not quite sure where the site mods come into this.

Comment: @JonClements I was thinking about a quick fix, not one that takes 6 to 8 weeks ...

Comment: You'd have to assume that if users research their problems well enough that they will inevitably learn about these language-specific sites.  Just from the Google hits, it favors linking to sites that have a language match.  Well, hopefully anyway.  I don't see this going wrong nearly as often as it could.

Comment: There's a weird opposite example when I was looking through questions in SO Portuguese and found a question asked in English!
At any rate, before I got to the "less ads" rep threshold, I used to see ads for SO Portuguese all the time while navigating SO (I'm from Brazil) so at least that one is sort of covered.

Comment: [stackexchange.com/sites#technology-traffic](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-traffic)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We'll update the blog post, good catch. There are probably other areas that need updating because we were pretty firm that we *weren't* going to localize until we finally made the decision to do so.

Some of the international sites are, themselves, self-advertising. We have some cross-linking of questions between the English and international sites that's visible if:

- Your browser is set to accept and use a non-English language that we support
- You land on a question on the English site that has been linked to a question on one of the international sites

.. at that time, you'll see a banner that says "We have a version of this question in [language] with answers of comparable quality." We include a link. It's not too intrusive or automatic, some folks would rather stay on the English site even if English isn't the language their browser uses.

Anyway, I've pinged the folks that handle the international buildout, thanks for bringing it up. The blog goes back quite a way and it's .. well .. easy to just forget about old guidance that is now completely stale.

Answer (score 23):

I know this isn't the official help page you requested, but for what it's worth, here's a non-official list of all the non-English Stack Overflow sites I was able to find [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology).

- [[image: Stack Overflow en español] **Stack Overflow en español**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) `[es.so]`
- [[image: スタック・オーバーフロー] **スタック・オーバーフロー**](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) `[ja.so]`
- [[image: Stack Overflow em Português]  **Stack Overflow em Português**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) `[pt.so]`
- [[image: Stack Overflow на русском] **Stack Overflow на русском**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) `[ru.so]`

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that there's no Mandarin, Hindustani, or Arabic (going by [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_total_number_of_speakers)). Since communication is integral to SO, it just seems like it would be important to hit the most-spoken languages (Mandarin, Hindustani, and Arabic are #1, #3, and #5). Or do the language distributions of tech people differ greatly from the general population? _Note that I was looking at most-spoken languages, not most **natively** spoken languages._

Comment: @AndrewMyers I'm not sure about this, (I just copied some links), but I think launching a different language SO site depends more on SE having employees who can do it than it does on how many users speak that language.

Comment: @AndrewMyers, It would also [need a different approach](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258288/use-of-ajax-googleapis-com-not-china-friendly) if Mandarin were to be supported for China.

Comment: @AndrewMyers I also wondered about this to some extent. Also because (and I guess I have to apologize for my ignorance here) I thought that Spanish and Portuguese would be "somewhat similar" (in regards to some overlap between the people who speak each language). However, in addition to the technical reasons that Don'tPanic mentioned, also considered that it may be a cultural thing. E.g. here in Germany everybody has to learn English, so there's hardly a point for something like a "Stack Overflow auf Deutsch", for example. I'm not sure whether this is the case in Japan, Brazil or Russia...

Comment: ... although, of course, there are knock-offs like http://codekicker.de/ or the one that is mentioned in the comment at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349131/users-political-display-name-triggering-government-action-against-users-who-vie#comment472858_349162 (as part of a discussion that points out some additional caveats for the special case of Mandarin/China...)

Comment: I added the magic links one can use in comments to link to the various sites. For instance, `[es.so]` becomes [es.so].

Answer (score -9):

Currently, there is no separate close option for questions posed in languages other than English -- they are closed under the heading "Unclear what you're asking" or flagged as "very low quality" ([How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content)). Both of these options are quite unsatisfactory, as far as I'm concerned (not being a native English speaker myself).

I would advocate for an extra close header. There is already a close header called something like "Wrong site" which gives the option of moving the question to sites like this one or Meta StackExchange. I would like to see a close header named 'Not answerable in English", with the option of moving the question to one of the non-English Stack Overflow sites.

Comment: Only good questions are candidates for migration. If you cannot read the question, you cannot judge it. A built-in option to send things to (for example) the Russian Stack Overflow, would cause people to send any question there that seems to be Russian.

Comment: I'm detecting a slight panic at encountering text written in a different language. In another question [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content), foreign variables were described as "gibberish" and now a fellow Dutchie frets over quality. Does the post contain more than two or three sentences? Do they contain the right words? (C++ in Japanse is still C++) Are there paragraphs interspersed with well-formatted code and a short sentence at the end? Is the question properly tagged? 2 points: good, 4 excellent!

Comment: If it's a good question that shows research effort, then by all means use a custom close reason to suggest migration. Or a custom moderator flag, where you vouch for the question being high quality. My concern is that, if migration to the non-English SO sites was a built-in option rather than a custom one, people would migrate recklessly.