# How can I remove any specific hat from my profile?

Tags: support, winter-bash

There is a certain hat that I received without meaning to, and I don't want it to be displayed in my profile.

Is it possible to remove a specific hat?

Comment: You can't, in the same way that you [can't remove specific badges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334052/can-i-remove-one-of-my-badges) from your profile.

Comment: You can wait until Jan 9, then all the hats will be gone. And if you don't wear the hats no one would notice anyway.

Comment: @approxiblue - jan 9th ok fine thanks

Comment: @animuson but they should provide the option rt?

Comment: There is an option "I Hate Hats"-->"Opt out of winter bash". Won't that help?

Comment: @Prabs i hope that it will remove my all hats rt?

Comment: I guess there is no option for removing specific hat.

Comment: What could you possibly want to remove one hat for?

Comment: @Lankymart i don't want secret hats. i want to remove

Comment: @Amruthls what do you have against secret hats, the design, the reason for receiving them or something else?

Comment: @Lankymart we are getting them without our knowledge rt? its my opinion i just want to remove it.. do you know how to remove?

Comment: @Amruthls One way is the following: 1) Hack the SE servers and obtain root access to the machines 2) Query their databases for hats data 3) Delete the hat you want from the rows you need 4) I believe SE has a few redundant databases and some offline backups, so you may need to hack a few more servers and also hide some malware to remove the information when the backups are put in place. 5) Done. I'll leave the details as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @Bakuriu But what if a secret hat is awarded for someone who successfully hacks the SE servers? How would you get rid of that one?!?

Comment: @Amruthls still what is it about secret hats that offends you? If you are this concerned about receiving a bonus hat, just don't bother with hats at all. The whole point of secret hats is they are there to find by performing unknown actions on the site, which is part of the fun!!

Comment: @Amruthls Is it you don't like receiving a hat for *"Any zero-scored, accepted answer that remains zero-scored for at least 12h after accepting."*? It's not like it's obvious it just comes up on your profile as *"this is a secret hat"*, if you wanted to find out you'd have to [dig deeper](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AFlWPYR7xnrQRsrVTS2Q_-sLhK7Ew1hLDz5oNKlu_n0/pub)...

Comment: @Lankymart my question is simple is it possible to remove specific hat or not ? if yes how ?

Comment: @Amruthls my answer is simple... No!

Comment: @Lankymart yea that is what i wanted :) thank you.

Comment: The "I hate hat"  option, can rhetorically remove a specific hat if you own only one hat.

Comment: I would love to get rid of my [tag:cakephp] badge and a couple of other ones. Alas no such luck. I'll survive though without losing much sleep over it. Because it's just dumb website.

Comment: I'm totally going to go and look at your hats now btw.

Comment: Makes sense. You wouldn't want anyone to know you used the search feature. As a future workaround, you could always use Google.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, you cannot remove specific hats from your profile, secret or otherwise.

I'm intrigued as to why you would want to though, what is it about secret hats that offends you?

If you are offended to the point of not wanting them displayed, your only option is to remove them altogether with the [I Hate Hats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340401/692942) option as [@prabs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2820534/prabs) points out.

However even if you opt out of hats other people can still see the ones you have earned by visiting your profile.

Comment: as a user i should have control on my profile rt? its my wish i don't want something so i will reject.

Comment: @Amruthls that's why the *"I Hate Hats"* option is provided. I guess they never thought there would be individual objections to certain hats though.

Comment: @Amruthls but this isn't a marriage proposal, it's digital assets on a website as part of a specific event for a prescribed period of time. Within that context it's all or nothing.

Comment: as we are engineers, we should understand users behavior, based on that only we should implement software's.

Comment: @Amruthls I'm sorry, going to have to leave it now as so far I've not seen a convincing argument for it and feel this will just continue back and forth otherwise.

Comment: i accept you. but i was searching for that option nothing else.

Comment: Even if you officially proclaim you Hate Hats, it's still possible to see what hats a user owns! Could that be considered a bug? (I might be wrong, I checked by looking at hat-less avatars. Please test with mine (I took all my hats off in remembrance of the princess).)

Comment: @RadLexus I am able to see the 14 hats you own [by visting your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2564301/rad-lexus?tab=topactivity#winter-bash)

Comment: @Tas: so there is no way to completely hide the fact one has a certain hat. Thanks for confirming; I was not sure because it might have been possible to always see your own hats but not those of strangers.

Answer (score -3):

There is an option "I Hate Hats"-->"Opt out of winter bash". Won't that help?

I didn't clicked it coz I Love Hats.

Once try that option. I guess it will work

[image]

**UPDATE**

The only way to take off hats is to opt out all at once. There is no way to remove specific hat

Comment: This doesn't remove _specific_ hat, it removes all.

Comment: Oh! Sad! I didn't give it a try. It was just a guess.

Comment: ya i referred this will remove all hats

Comment: You shouldn't answer with a "guess" but with something you know is a solution or a workaround.

Comment: @EAmez wat? Where do all these answers on SO come from then?

Comment: I hope they come from developers knowledge... If not, I've been very lucky with my queries in this site LOL

Comment: @EAmez oh you just don't understand Stack Overflow. The answers there  come from *gamification*. Knowledge is not necessary. The *desire to answer* is the only that counts. So this answer is pretty legit

Comment: Guess or not, this is the closest answer OP is going to get. As [animuson said in the comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340400/how-can-i-remove-any-specific-hat-from-my-profile?cb=1#comment425853_340400), there's no way to remove a specific hat. The closest option, if OP truly hates having this particular hat displayed, is to opt out altogether.

Comment: @tas I agree they can't give a meaningful reason why they just want to remove secret hats, this is there best option.

Comment: @YourCommonSense then I guess I'm taking thing too seriously for this ;)

Comment: I hate hat, will remove a specific hat if you have only one hat. Its it possible to own only one hat is going to be the next question..

Comment: Opting out of hats doesn't provide much  advantage here over staying opted in and not wearing one, either way you still earn hats and other people can see them from your profile.